# How to make a image loop across the screen [horizontally]

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

This is what I got but I am getting errors as you see in the picture. 
I have the IBOutlets for UIImageView *bottomGroundContinue and one for *bottomGround
@implementation viewController

[image]

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL keepGoing;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *bottomGround;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *bottomGroundContinue;

- (void)getReady {


    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomGround.png"];


    self.bottomGround = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:theImage];
    self.bottomGroundContinue = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:theImage];


    self.bottomGround.frame = self.view.bounds;
    self.bottomGRoundContinue.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.bounds, self.bottomGround.bounds.size.width, 0.0);

    [self.view addSubview:self.bottomGround];
    [self.view addSubview:self.bottomGroundContinue];
    self.keepGoing = YES;
}

- (void)go {

    CGFloat width = self.bottomGround.bounds.size.width;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        self.bottomGround.frame = CGRectOffset(self.bottomGround.frame, -width, 0);
        self.bottomGroundContinue.frame = CGRectOffset(self.bottomGroundContinue.frame, -width, 0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        if (self.keepGoing) {
            // now B is where A began, so swap them and reposition B
            UIImageView *temp = self.bottomGround;
            self.bottomGround  = self.bottomGroundContinue;
            self.bottomGroundContinue = temp;
            self.bottomGroundContinue.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.bounds, self.view.bounds.size.width, 0.0);
            // recursive call, but we don't want to wind up the stack
            [self performSelector:@selector(go) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring properties inside of @implementation.  You need to declare them inside of @interface.

Comment: Okay now it took most of the errors. Now I am having 2 Semantic issues: Autosynthesized property 'bottomGroundContinue' will use synthesized instance variable '_bottomGroundContinue', not existing instance variable 'bottomGroundContinue'----and---- :Autosynthesized property 'bottomGround' will use synthesized instance variable '_bottomGround', not existing instance variable 'bottomGround'

Comment: How are you hooking up your IBOutlets in your viewController header/implementation file? It should look like this: `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *bottomGround;`

Comment: `@interface gameViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL keepGoing;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *bottomGround;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *bottomGroundContinue;

@end`

Comment: I still have the issue... :(

Comment: I'm going to bet a nickel that you have two instance variables in your viewController header that have the same name as the properties you declare in the class extension.  Remove the instance variables! And make sure "IBOutlet" is included right before "UIImageView" of both of your properties.

Comment: Is there an easier way to do this ?